# Как распарсить строку на переменные?

Tags: c#

Дан текстовик: random.txt
В нëм строки: 123123:123123:123123, такого вида.
Как можно эти строки распарсить на 3 переменные?

Comment: `myString.Split(':')`

Comment: ... `.Select(int.Parse).ToArray()`

Comment: @tym32167, можно подробнее пожалуйста. Как брать текстовик (который будет лежать в папке с программной) и парсить его? Очень сильно благодарен.

Comment: `File.ReadLines(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "random.txt")).Select(line => line.Split(':').Select(int.Parse).ToArray())`

Comment: @vladd, если Вам не сложно, то как мне можно дальше работать с этими строками? Есть код? Должно получиться, что то типо: string number = array[0].

Answer (score 2):

Ну например как-то так:

```
var filepath = Path.Combine(
    Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
    "random.txt");

foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filepath))
{
    int[] numbers = line.Split(':').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
    int first = numbers[0];
    ...
}
```

Comment: А как работать с несколькими переменными. Если я пишу после "int first = numbers[0];", следующий код: "int first = date1[1];" , то выходит ошибка: Использование локальной переменной "numbers", которой не присвоено значение.

Comment: @Millano: А что такое `date1` у вас?

Comment: в вопросе самом 3 переменные должны быть. date1 - это пароль у меня

Comment: А можно код, который у вас не работает? Мой код компилируется, вы как-то поменяли, и он у вас не компилируется.

Comment: ваш код выше работает, но как мне добавить ещё пару переменных?

Comment: `int first = numbers[0]; int second = numbers[1]; int third = numbers[2];`?